# Assign Workbooks to Array when opening Multiple Workbooks by ParamArray

Tags: excel, vba

I open multiple files using ParamArray.

How do I assign the workbooks to an array to access them individually? For example, to get the last row of each workbook.

The error is

> subscript out of range

```
Sub main()
 Call COMBINED_FILES("wk1.csv","wk2.xlsx","wk3.xls","wk4.csv")
End Sub

Sub COMBINED_FILES(ParamArray SOURCE_FILE_NAME_WITH_EXTENTION() As Variant) 

 Dim MASTER_WORK_BOOK_PATH As String
 MASTER_WORK_BOOK_PATH = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\"

 Dim MASTER_WORK_BOOK As Workbook
 Set MASTER_WORK_BOOK = ActiveWorkbook

 Dim I As Integer

 For I = 1 To UBound(SOURCE_FILE_NAME_WITH_EXTENTION)
     Dim Resultworkbook() As Workbook
     Set Resultworkbook(I) = Workbooks.Open(MASTER_WORK_BOOK_PATH & SOURCE_FILE_NAME_WITH_EXTENTION(I))
     Debug.Print SOURCE_FILE_NAME_WITH_EXTENTION(I)
 Next I
End sub
```

Comment: WHY ARE THE VARIABLES AND THE ROUTINES WITH CAPS LOCK?

Comment: Resultworkbook is not dimentionned. Use Redim to set it size.

Comment: @Vityata it's just my preference in this Macro

Comment: And put the declaration and resizing out of the For loop, since the final size is known before.

Comment: As Vincent says, and you can set it to be the same size as the array you're passing.

Comment: paramarray is zero-based, so you're missing the first element.

Comment: @VincentG I got it to work! and since I don't know how many files would be put into so I put it within the loop. Thank you.

Comment: @SJR I see what you meant. Thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- The parenthesis of the arguments in `COMBINED_FILES` are not needed
- `Dim MASTER_WORK_BOOK As Workbook` is not used
- Avoid ActiveWorkbook - [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba)
- Avoid `Integer` - [Why Use Integer Instead of Long?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26409117/why-use-integer-instead-of-long)
- There is a convention in VBA, to use Caps lock only for constants
- If you loop on an array, try `For i = LBound(array) to Ubound(array)`
- `ReDim ResultWorkbook(UBound(sourceFileNameWithExtension)) As Workbook` is used to both initialize and dimensionize the `ResultWorkbook()`. If it is not dimensionzed, it cannot be accessed.

This code works:

```
Sub Main()
    CombinedFiles "wk1.xlsx", "wk2.xlsx", "wk3.xlsx", "wk4.xlsx"
End Sub

Sub CombinedFiles(ParamArray sourceFileNameWithExtension() As Variant)

    Dim masterWorkbookPath As String
    masterWorkbookPath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\"

    Dim i As Long
    ReDim ResultWorkbook(UBound(sourceFileNameWithExtension)) As Workbook
    For i = LBound(sourceFileNameWithExtension) To UBound(sourceFileNameWithExtension)
        Set ResultWorkbook(i) = Workbooks.Open(masterWorkbookPath & sourceFileNameWithExtension(i))
        Debug.Print sourceFileNameWithExtension(i)
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: I got it to work and being able to grab the last row numbers for each workbook. Thanks for all the suggestions. I'll look through these.

Comment: "use Caps lock only for constants" - meh. Keep `SCREAMCASE` for SQL, constants are fine in `PascalCase` like everything else =)

Comment: @MathieuGuindon - idk, when I see caps lock I feel being screamed upon. But for SQL it is one of the two standards, indeed.